# Google Analytics Event Tracking onClick Code

Tags: google-analytics

I'm trying to set up event tracking on my web site but can't get it working correctly.

My tracking code:

```
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-420xxxxxxx', 'mywebsite.org');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
```

My event tracking code:

```
<a href="#PurchasePanelLink" class="uk-button uk-button-primary" onClick="$('#PurchasePanel').show(); _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Button', 'Click', 'Purchase Details',, false]);">Purchase Details</a>
```

Answer (score 63, accepted):

You are mixing classic code with universal code. It will not work. You need to replace this:

```
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Button', 'Click', 'Purchase Details',, false]);
```

With this:

```
ga('send', 'event', 'Button', 'Click', 'Purchase Details');
```

GAJS reference for Events: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events#implementation

Comment: Man I love stack overflow. Everybody is so helpful. Thank you!

Comment: Is onClick still supported? Can't see any mention of this type of implementation in GA's latest guide: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events#implementation

Comment: FYI, here is the *syntax reference*  https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/upgrade/reference/gajs-analyticsjs

Comment: @jnthnclrk that's because their documentation is pretty dumb and confusing. Thank god we have SO to turn to...

Answer (score 12):

Event hits can be sent using the send command. According to new analytics.js

Syntax:

```
ga('send', 'event', [eventCategory], [eventAction], [eventLabel], [eventValue], [fieldsObject]);
```

For example if you want to track purchase event

```
ga('send', 'event', 'Button', 'Click', 'Purchase Details');
```

**Here:-**

**eventCategory** is Button. It is required field and its Value Type is text

**eventAction** is Click. It is required field and its Value Type is text

**eventLabel** is Purchase Details. It is optional field and its Value Type is text

**eventValue** is null. It is optional field and its Value Type is integer

Answer (score 8):

it looks like you're using the new [`analytics.js`](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events) instead of `ga.js`, so you'll want to use the proper event tracking method set:

```
ga('send', 'event', 'category', 'action');
```