# Google Analytics onClick to send an event

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I asked a [question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/110004/google-analytics-exclude-from-stats-if-user-clicks-on-a-particular-link-when-v) on the Webmasters Stack Exchange about how to track which users were clicking on an application login URL on our website.

The set up is that I have a website, `https://www.example.com` and a web application on a subdomain, `https://app.example.com/login.php`.

Both sites have the same Google Analytics tracking code installed.

In the navigation on `https://www.example.com` I have a URL to the login page of the web application:

```
<a href="https://app.example.com/login.php">Login</a>
```

All I'm trying to do is show in Analytics who has clicked on this link.

So one of the answers given involves using Events. I've read both Google's [Event Tracking documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events) and [Google Analytics Event Tracking onClick Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18605219/google-analytics-event-tracking-onclick-code) but I can't get this to work programatically.

I've tried adding an `onClick` to my anchor as follows:

```
<a href="https://app.example.com/login.php" onClick="ga('send', 'event', 'Web Application', 'Login', 'Logged in via public website'); ">Login</a>
```

This doesn't seem to record anything in Analytics - nothing is showing up under Events, including the Real Time data section.

However, I'm not convinced this works from a programatic perspective because if I run the `ga()` command in my browser console:

```
ga('send', 'event', 'Web Application', 'Login', 'Logged in via public website')
```

It just returns `undefined`. I don't understand this as my website has the Analytics tracking code installed, and already uses things such as `ga('send', 'pageview');`. There is loads of data in Analytics for the website, so clearly it is running.

I feel like this - and all of the documentation - is really complicated to do what should be a very simple task. Please can someone enlighten me as to how (or indeed if) this is possible?

Comment: Returning "undefined" (or rather returning nothing) is expected behavior. Look in the network tab if there is a call to google analytics (request path starts with /collect?v=1&... ). Code looks correct.

Comment: I can see a request being made to a URL starting `/collect?=v=1...`. So how long does this take to appear in Analytics? Presumably it's under Events but I can't see anything in there for it.

Comment: The page may be unloading before the event finishes firing. You could stop the link from loading by adding `ga('send', 'event', 'Web Application', 'Login', 'Logged in via public website'); return false` in the onclick of the anchor tag.

Answer (score 0):

Your code:

```
ga('send', 'event', 'Web Application', 'Login', 'Logged in via public website')
```

From the Documentation [events](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events)

> eventCategory text    yes Typically the object that was interacted with
>   (e.g. 'Video')
>
> eventAction   text    yes The type of interaction (e.g. 'play')
>
> eventLabel    text    no  Useful for categorizing events (e.g. 'Fall
>   Campaign')
>
> eventValue **integer** no  A numeric value associated with the
>   event (e.g. 42)

The last value is an int not a string **'Logged in via public website'** is not valid

```
ga('send', 'event', 'Web Application', 'Login', 42)
```

Comment: Are you sure? After `ga('send', 'event'` according to the documentation there are 4 possible parameters? The 4th one is the int value. So I only had 3 ('Web Application', 'Login', 'Logged in via public website') e.g https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events#examples

Comment: @Andy You are correct. While yes, the eventValue is an integer, your event call only uses the first three parameters.